# Get City and Country name from session to database Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, session, session-variables

I wanna try to get `data` from users `Session`.

In `sessions.php` - i was write `driver -> database` and in file `.env` repeat this.

Next i'll use `php artisan table:sessions` and create default Sessions Table look's like this (with custom fields)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
        });
    }
```

But in rows `city` and `country` i can't insert data. What i'm doing wrang?

Comment: "_But in rows city and country i can't insert data_" Why not? How do you insert? Do you get errors?

Comment: @brombeer i have NULL in all of this rows

Comment: @brombeer i think it's unreal to take this data... so maybe i must trying to take custom scripts for this problem

Comment: If `city` and `country` are custom fields that are not available in vanilla Laravel sessions then Yes, you'd need custom code to fill those fields - Laravel won't "magically" fill them for you